# Как передать значение объекта-родителя, во вложенный массив с объектами?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется массив

```
const array = []
const sortedArr = array
    .map((docs) => ({
      titleID: docs.titleID,
      data: docs.data
    }))
```

нужно передать поле titleID во все объекты data, где data собирается в другой функции

```
return data.map((item) => ({
    id: item.Id,
    name: item.Name,
    titleID: ????????????????
  }));
```

пробовал через

```
init : function() {
      this.parent = this;
      delete this.init;
      return this;
    },
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможно, ваш вопрос не совсем понятен. Попробуйте его переформулировать и добавить тестовый завершённый код с примером исходных структур и желаемого результата.

Comment: А как вы получаете доступ к свойству объекта `.data` просто обращаясь к нему `data`? Где-то там же, где происходит присваивание переменной `data` наверняка можно и получить значение `.titleID`.